# Showing Custom ListView in the app with Actionbar with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am creating an email client for android for which I want to use navigation drawer. I need to populate the list of mails in the view for each section.
How can I do it ??
PS: I am building for SDK version 10

Comment: As far as I know you need to setup support libraries for that. and there are some good tutorials out there by which you can learn to implement navigation drawer in your app. like [link]http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: The Navigation Drawer is created as a default android project...Now what I need to do in that is for each section I need to display a list of emails.....
What I need to work with ListView or ListFragments??

Comment: I suggest you using Custom Listview for that And It is easy to implement.